# why does listing the actual constructor of a class in javascript important

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototypal-inheritance, prototype-programming

I was reading on javascript garden http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/  about prototype in javascript and one of its example goes like this:

```
function Foo() {
    this.value = 42;
}
Foo.prototype = {
    method: function() {}
};

function Bar() {}

// Set Bar's prototype to a new instance of Foo
Bar.prototype = new Foo();
Bar.prototype.foo = 'Hello World';

// Make sure to list Bar as the actual constructor <-------------------
Bar.prototype.constructor = Bar;
```

Notice the line that reads Make sure to list Bar as the actual constructor. I really am lost about what this does/is. I have tried making new instances of Bar() with and without the last line. But call "value" or "method" on those instances return the exact same things. So I wonder, what's the need (I assume there must be one) of specifying the constructor?

Thank You!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every function has a `prototype` property, it's assigned when the function object is created, it points to a newly created object that inherits from `Object.prototype`, and it has a `constructor` property, that simply points back to the function itself.

The purpose of the `prototype` property is to give a way to implement inheritance, using constructor functions. When you call a function with the `new` operator, it will create a new object that inherits from that constructor's `prototype`.

Now, the purpose of the `constructor` property is to have a way to refer back to the constructor that has created an object, for example:

```
function Foo () {}
// default value of the property:
Foo.prototype.constructor == Foo; // true
```

This property is inherited by the "instances" of `Foo`, so you can know which constructor was used to create an object:

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.constructor == Foo;
```

If you assign a new object to the function's prototype, this relationship is lost:

```
function Bar () {}
Bar.prototype = { inherited: 1 };

Bar.prototype.constructor == Bar;    // false
Bar.prototype.constructor == Object; // true
```

And it affects also the instances of the function:

```
var bar = new Bar();
bar.constructor == Bar;    // false
bar.constructor == Object; // true
```

Another similar case is when you have two or more levels of inheritance using constructors, the most common way is used to denote the inheritance relationship between the functions, is to assign the `prototype` property of the second level, e.g.:

```
function Parent() {}

function Child () {}
Child.prototype = new Parent();
```

The above code has several problems, first, it executes the logic of the parent constructor to create the inheritance relationship, but that's another story, in the above example the `constructor` property is also affected, since we replace completely the `Child.prototype` object:

```
var child = new Child();
child.constructor == Parent; // true
```

If we replace replace the value of the `constructor` property of `Child.prototype` after assigning it, it will show the expected behavior:

```
function Child() {}
Child.prototype = new Parent();
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

var child = new Child();
child.constructor == Child; // true
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation. It all makes sense. The only thing that still bugs me but I can overlook is it looks a bit circular in the Child.prototype.constructor = Child

Comment: @Nik, You're welcome! Yeah, it's indeed circular by design, e.g.: `Object.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor == Object;` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this has to do with instantiating Bar with the new keyword. I believe using new will look for Bar.prototype.constructor. Before that line the object linked to Bar.prototype.contructor is of type Foo so when instantiated without that line it will make a Foo object instead of a Bar object.

Comment: Thanks Keith! ;That's a succinct and to the point explanation as well