# Constructor assignment on prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

When making the prototypal inheritance, it's asked to refer the child's constructor back to itself below,

```
A = function() {} 
B = function() {} 
B.prototype = new A;
B.prototype.constructor = B;
```

What would take adverse effect if not?

**EDIT**

- As `@GGG` & `@CMS` have explained, the constructor alignment takes no
  effect on creating the child object by `new Child(...)`, but is
  necessary to correctly reflect the child object's constructor later.
- `@GGG` has also suggested a defensive alternative to extend
  the prototype chain. While `Child.prototype = new Parent(...)`
  includes parent's properties to child, `Child.prototype =
  Object.create(Parent.prototype)` doesn't.

Comment: See: [why does listing the actual constructor of a class in javascript important](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719119)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, please don't do this:

```
B.prototype = new A;
```

Do this instead ([shim](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) `Object.create` for old browsers):

```
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
```

As for `constructor`, nothing will break if you don't do this, but if you don't:

```
A = function() {};
var a = new A();
console.log(a.constructor); // A

B = function() {};
var b = new B();
console.log(b.constructor); // A (!)
```

...setting the `constructor` property of the prototype back to the actual constructor function allows you to do this:

```
B.prototype.constructor = B;
var b = new B();
console.log(b.constructor); // B
```